# Empty string in Python after append

Tags: python, append

This is my code

```
import re

filenames = []

while True:
    filename_input = input("Filename? ")
    pattern = r'\[.*?\]'
    re_filename = re.sub(pattern,"",filename_input)
    filenames.append(re_filename)
    if (filename_input == ""):
        break
print(filenames)
```

The function of this program is when a user enters a filename with additional parentheses, it removes the parentheses and the contents, appending it to a list and displaying all the filenames entered(after removing parentheses and content), the program will stop after an empty filename is entered.

But for some reason, I keep getting this output with an additional empty ' ' behind.

How do I get rid of it?

Here's the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Please try to [explain the code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). When and where do you check for loop termination? When and where do you check for loop termination in relation to the `append` call? The order in which you do things really matters.

Comment: You have to put the `if (filename_input == ""): break` before the `append`.

Comment: For future question please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't post images of text, copy-paste text *as text* into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because at the last input you enter nothing. SO a empty value gets appended to the list. To get rid of this. Put the whole thing in a `if` block like:

```
import re

filenames = []

while True:
    filename_input = input("Filename? ")
    if not filename_input == "":
        pattern = r'\[.*?\]'
        re_filename = re.sub(pattern,"",filename_input)
        filenames.append(re_filename)
    else:
        break

print(filenames)
```

Comment: Welcome. If this fixes your issue, then please click on the big check mark to accept it as the answer of this question.

Comment: You don't need a complete `if`-`else` block

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you break out of the loop after the empty input has already been appended to the array, move the exit condition to the line directly after getting input from the user.

Comment: That's the way to go here